# Shell - grep/sed substring from variable

Tags: shell, sed, find, substring

I've been trying to get this to work for 2hours now but I haven't managed.
In a jenkins shell command I wrote the following:

```
full_HTML=$( curl http://website.com/ )
echo "$full_HTML" | sed -ne 's/<table class="pane" id="buildQueue">\(.*\)<\/table>.*/\1/'
```

So I've started by storing the source of a webpage in a variable. From that variable I'd like to extract the following tag:

```
<table class="pane" id="buildQueue"> 

...

...

...

</table>
```

Could anybody suggest what I might be doing wrong? I've been looking at it for so long I'm afraid I'm missing something really simple.

Thanks!

EDIT1:
I get no output. If I remove the -n from sed it echos the entire $full_HTML variable which contains the whole page source of the respective webpage.

Also I'm on a linux machine with sed --version = GNU sed version 4.1.5

EDIT2:
Note that there is only one  but there are multiple tables across the entire page source.

Comment: edit your question to include what you **are** getting as a result. Also, what OS and `sed --version` do you use. This can make a big difference as to what is available. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution with grep:

```
full_HTML=$( curl http://website.com/ )
echo $full_HTML | grep -Po '\K<table class="pane" id="buildQueue">(.*?)<\/table>'
```

Where the \K part removes everything before the respective table and the (.*?) returns what is in between this particular tag.

Answer (score 1):

using line range in sed

```
echo "$full_HTML"|sed -n '/ *<table class="pane" id="buildQueue"> */,/ *<\/table> */p'
```

Alternative method by building a multi pattern line using sed

```
echo "$full_HTML"|sed -n '/ *<table class="pane" id="buildQueue"> */{:loop N;/ *<\/table> */! b loop;/ *<\/table> */p}'
```

EDIT: Using awk

```
echo "$full_HTML"|awk '/ *<table class="pane" id="buildQueue"> */,/ *<\/table> */{print}'
```